# Visual Studio Green Warning Underlines

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm having a strange problem in Visual Studio. Today it's decided to add green wiggly underlines to my code in the aspx files:

[image]

I've tried to remove some of the code I've written today in the hope of finding what is tripping up the IDE but I can't work it out.

Everything compiles and runs fine.  When I hover my mouse over any of the underlines I get the following message "This name contains uppercase characters, which is not allowed".

I've got this on all of my content pages.

Has anyone seen this before or can suggest how to work out what might be wrong?

**And by the way, the code passes W3C validation**

Comment: May be an unclosed tag or a bad nesting

Comment: I'm sorry to have to tell you this... but you have the Green Wigglies.  You have six months to live.  =O

Comment: No offense... But the message is exactly what it means. You have uppercase characters in your HTML which causes it to not validate. They are validation warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK I found the problem. I hope this helps someone.

After hacking up various pages I eventually unearthed a single line complaining about a telerik control on my Master Page (the IDE had no problem with any other telerik controls elsewhere). The warning was "unrecognized tag prefix or device filter 'telerik'". The solution still built at this point.

After some investigating I discovered I had an old version of the Telerik.Web.Design.dll in my bin folder. I removed it, recompiled and re-opened the pages and lo and behold the error was gone.

Nothing to do with UPPERCASE tags at all.

Answer (score 5):

it is because

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

this line

which indicate that you html must be comptiable with the xtml rules.

**Rules of XHTML**

```
XHTML elements must be properly nested
XHTML elements must always be closed
XHTML elements must be in lowercase
XHTML documents must have one root element
```

check it over here : http://www.w3schools.com/xhtml/xhtml_html.asp

Comment: It isn't very helpful that it gives absolutely no clue as to where the problem is...

Comment: @cusimar9 - follow the rules of xhtml to remove those green line in your html..............read more about xhtml

Comment: Yes but that is RENDERED html. Visual Studio is parsing the code it sees and is saying it's invalid, and it's correct, because you have uppercase tags.

Comment: But the tags that are shown in the screenshot are default properties picked up by Intellisense - they ARE uppercase!

Comment: "But the tags that are shown in the screenshot are default properties picked up by Intellisense - they ARE uppercase!" Youngster, you would do well to stop expecting logic and consistency.

Comment: @cusimar9 - You can set visual studio to create ASP/HTML tags in lowercase.

Comment: Tools > Text Editor > HTML > Formatting

Comment: Set Server Tags -> Lowercase  /  Server Attributes -> Lowercase